# NGINX keeps file descriptors open for deleted files

Tags: nginx

I have a server running nginx proxying to a python API, a user will request an mp4 file which will be generated and written to /tmp/cache and served with nginx. Some time later (~ 20 seconds) the file will be deleted by the python process but that file remains held by nginx meaning the space is unusable and eventually the user runs out of cache space causing the entire application to fail.

Relevant parts of nginx config:

```
http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log /dev/stdout main;

    # send headers in one piece, it is better than sending them one by one
    tcp_nopush on;

    sendfile on;

    keepalive_timeout 65;

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript image/svg+xml image/x-icon image/bmp image/png image/gif image/jpeg image/jpg;
    gzip_proxied no-cache no-store private expired auth;
    gzip_vary on;

    server {
        listen 5000;

        location /cache/ {
            internal; # This tells nginx it's not accessible from the outside
            alias /tmp/cache/;
        }

        location /api/ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            expires off;

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
            proxy_pass http://frigate_api/;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

relevant python api code:

```py
@bp.route("/<camera_name>/start/<float:start_ts>/end/<float:end_ts>/clip.mp4")
def recording_clip(camera_name, start_ts, end_ts):
    download = request.args.get("download", type=bool)

    ...

    file_name = f"clip_{camera_name}_{start_ts}-{end_ts}.mp4"
    path = f"/tmp/cache/{file_name}"

    response = make_response()
    response.headers["Content-Description"] = "File Transfer"
    response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "video/mp4"
    if download:
        response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=%s" % file_name
    response.headers["Content-Length"] = os.path.getsize(path)
    response.headers[
        "X-Accel-Redirect"
    ] = f"/cache/{file_name}"  # nginx: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxXSendfile

    return response
```

we can see that after the file has been deleted by python, nginx keeps the file open meaning the space is still being used

```bash
# lsof -n | grep /tmp |grep deleted
nginx      130                  root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  152 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  156 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  159 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  163 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  166 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  169 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  173 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  177 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  181 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  185 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  189 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  194 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  197 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  203 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  211 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  216 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  221 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  225 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  230 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  235 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  240 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  244 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  247 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  251 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  254 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  257 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  261 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  263 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  266 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  269 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  272 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
nginx      130  276 nginx       root   27r      REG              0,122 561200658                60 /tmp/cache/clip_front_doorbell_cam_1674691364.607239-1674692415.428497.mp4 (deleted)
```

is there any way to disable this behavior?